# Are 'Pre-Authorized' Annotations' Results Cached?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**In Spring Boot, are `@PreAuthorize("@bean.checkAuthorization(#argument)")` calls cached on a per-request basis?**

As a minimal example, suppose a `@Controller` has the following REST endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/api/test") public String testAuthorization() {
    String argument;

    String foo = service.foo(argument);
    String bar = service.bar(argument); // same arguments
    return bar + foo;
}
```

and the `foo` and `bar` methods in `service` are defined as follows:

```
@PreAuthorize("@bean.checkAuthorization(#argument)")
public String foo(String argument) {
    return "hello";
}


@PreAuthorize("@bean.checkAuthorization(#argument)")
public String bar(String argument) {
    return "world";
}
```

**Use case.** Given that `Bean.checkAuthorization(argument)` is a costly function to run (*e.g.* it makes a database call), but is stateless (*i.e.* its result for a given argument will not change with multiple calls), it is only necessary to make the call once per request. Therefore, is it possible to cache the result for the whole request, but ensure that the check is performed on every request? (no long term cache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is ***not*** a good idea.

In implementing something like this, you're made vulnerable to a cache poisoning attack; that is, you expose yourself to the threat of anyone who is not authorized through your database call to be authorized in the manner you don't want them to be.

It's *preferable* to take the slight performance hit in determining if a user should be allowed access to a protected resource than having that resource leak.

The better option may be to investigate what's making the database call so expensive, or to convince the business that this is an expense that needs to be paid to safeguard this resource.

Comment: Makoto, the point here is that the *same* database request is being made several times since the same authentication check is being made for different resources. Can you elaborate on why caching (during only the lifetime of the HTTP request, that is) is a security risk?

Comment: For example, a user wants a cup of coffee; I need to get a cup and coffee to satisfy the request. The PreAuthorize check is being made on the cup and coffee level but the two checks resolve to the same database call — what is wrong with memoizing the check result until the cup of coffee is served?

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne:  Caching implies *reuse*.  To use your coffee analogy, caching the check would be equivalent to reusing the same cup whenever *anyone* wanted a cup of coffee.  I get the impression that you're fighting the justification for the authorization check to begin with; maybe you could illustrate what the check is, more concretely, so that you can help clear up *my* misunderstanding of it.

Comment: I think @Makoto is implying, but not really explaining very well, is that any attempt to cache at request-scope is going to rely on a thread local which will need to be _very_ carefully cleaned up for every possible return path of that thread back to the servlet executor pool.

Comment: I think the 'Spring' way to do this is to implement the Spring Security `UserDetails` interface and the associated service to provide it then add the result of the authorization check as a `GrantedAuthority` to the user's collection. Spring Security guarantees that the security context will be clean for new requests.

Comment: At first I was reticent to accept this answer because ‘theoretically’ it *should* work, though I understand now that it may be difficult to sanitise. I will post a sample project later to get your thoughts on it, and whether there is a security flaw.

Comment: @Makoto If you're interested in taking a look, https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-request-level-memoization/ has a sample that resembles what I am looking for closely. The key definition is the following: `@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "request")`,  a synonym of `@RequestScope` which is defined here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-request. Based on running a few tests, I've found that it *seems* to work in a simple setting. I'd be curious to know your opinions on implementing my setup using this.

Answer (score 0):

Just enable caching: `@EnableCaching`, and put `@Cacheable("checkauth")` on top of the `checkAuthorization` method.

**Edit** I realised that my answer wasn't for request as the comment below stated. There are definitely some fancy ways of doing that, such as here: [Caching per request with Spring](https://okraskat.github.io/caching-per-request-with-spring/) which uses `AOP`.

But so complicated! Just have I imagine most requests would take under a second for most modern web applications having a retention policy of `@Cached(expire = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)` would do the trick, pre-optimisation is the devil.

But I find this approach all really non standard for such a standard problem. Instead I suggest that you have roles: `FOO` & `BAR`, which will allow you to simply annotate your methods with: `hasRole('FOO')`, `hasRole('BAR')`.

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
 
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
 
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (checkAuthorizationFoo(user)) user.addRole("FOO");
        if (checkAuthorizationBar(user)) user.addRole("BAR");

        return new user;
    }
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('FOO')")
public String foo(String argument) {

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('BAR')")
public String bar(String argument) {
```

Realise though that this isn't lazy and your `checkAuthorization` methods are always being called, which is a downside with this approach. You could make it lazy with a bit of work probably but again just be careful how much optimisation you go out and do.

Comment: No, I didn't downvote your answer, hence I cannot unvote. It was someone else.

Comment: Not sure who down-voted it, but I upvoted it to make sure it wasn't negative. I am, however, not sure that this truly answers my question. See the comments on the other answer.

Comment: Also, I respectfully disagree with the use of a time-based, request-indiscriminate cache. Whatever security flaws with cache poisoning exist with a normal cache are retained with this method.

Comment: Use the bottom method then.